# Using arduino framework how many instances of SoftwareSerial can use simultaneously with esp32

Tags: esp32, softwareserial, uart

Ussing popular library https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial/ can I have multiple softwareSerial ports (for example 6 ports).

I’m the readme say  “ several instances can be active at the same time” but don’t answer a quantity just say several.
Also don’t say if the instances will operate normal or will have some issue.
Ref: https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial/#readme

Will be great to read an answer from someone with experience with the this specific library and arduino framework.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Third paragraph of the readme that you link to: "The same functionality is given as the corresponding AVR library **but several instances can be active at the same time.**"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question links directly to the answer...

Comment: @Majenko To be fair "several" is not a good answer to the question "how many". Do you know of any limits on the number of simultaneously listening ports (besides the needed pins)?

Comment: @chrisl "several" is the only answer that can be given. You can have more than one. How many will depend on many factors, like what baud rate your are using, how often data is being received, what else the program is doing at the same time, etc. Factors that cannot be predicted by us. So the answer is "yes you can have several" and that's as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question that has an answer. There are far too many variables to say "You can have X ports at once".

How many you can have depends on such things as:

- **The baud rates you are using:** faster baud rates will mean more processing and thus less processing for other ports to run.
- **How often data is received:** A port that's not receiving anything isn't using any processing. You could have lots and lots of ports, but if only one is receiving anything it's not much different to only having one port.
- **What else your program is doing:** You have finite resources. The more you use in your program the less are available for other things. You're running an RTOS, and resources and processing are time-sliced between tasks.

You can maximise your port availability by being crafty and careful with executing certain things on each core - for example if you have two heavily used ports it could be good to have one bound to each of your two cores (assuming a dual core ESP32) so they don't interfere with each other as much.

So a quantity cannot be given. Nor can a prediction about how reliable they would be. From the way it's purported to operate, though, the quantity is likely to be "quite a few" and there should be no problems, as long as you don't have too many.